# How can I import in Xcode fragments of html code between tags? Is it possible to indicate in which line of code I want to search?

Tags: html, xcode

I want to extract some code from a webiste what is updated everyday, but I need to extract several items about 60-80 paired in groups of two and I need to find them on the text.

Last year I saw how to do it indicating beggining and ending tag to search in between but I can´t find it again.

Could anybody help me?

THNX!